# AWS Certificate Manager: Get SSL certificate for IP for IP adress instead of domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ip, https, certificate

Is there a possibility to get or use a SSL certificate in AWS Certificate Manager for a public IP instead of a domain name?

I need a SSL certificate for my EC2 server on AWS, but I don't want to register it under a domain name right now.

Comment: It's good to always have one domain name you can use (with infinite subdomains) for in-development sites like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a self-signed certificate to be used with specific applications within your server and this will necessarily show as such to anyone using that service but should work fine for many applications.

I believe that certs signed by a CA need to use the DNS name, *not* the IP for a public certificate so that is what you have to use with AWS.

Answer (score 0):

SSL/TLS certificates do NOT work with IP addresses. They need to be attached to a DNS name.

This will work:

```
mydomain.amazonaws.com
thisismydomain.com
webserver-1.my.local.network
```

This will NOT work:

```
192.168.1.50
14.156.34.26
```

Comment: Wrong assertion.
Right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37063612/7104681